# invalid encoding when uploading an image to rails using javascript

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload

I'm using qqfileupload (http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) to create a single drag & drop image upload interface.

The request is being sent to rails, and my rails console is returning

```
!! Unexpected error while processing request: invalid %-encoding (����JFIFdd��Ducky��Adobed)
```

which I assume is rails attempting to read the file.

I set my controller to output

```
return render :text => params
```

thinking that I could look at what the server was recieving, but I only get the Unexpected error again, which to me says that Rails is hitting this error before getting to the controller.

The params from the javascript console shows

```
http://localhost:3000/users?qqfile=me.jpg&first_name=&last_name=
```

the first and last fields are supposed to be blanks.

Answer (score 0):

I stared following this tutorial http://css-tricks.com/ajax-image-uploading/, which looked very similar to the case I was already using, and it lead to this download script http://valums.com/ajax-upload/, which is almost identical to the one I had before, but somehow is slightly different and doesn't return the error above.

Hopefully this helps somebody out.

Comment: In the end, this tutorial helped straighten me out after another day of frustration. Hopefully this helps somebody . http://www.jigsawboys.com/2010/10/06/ruby-on-rails-ajax-file-upload-with-valum/